# RPIO issue with servo

Tags: servo

I've followed the instructions in the answers on GPIO/RPIO. I still get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Python_Ed/RPIO_server_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from RPIO import PWM
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/RPIO-2.0.0_beta1-py3.4-linux-armv7l.egg/RPIO/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    import RPIO._GPIO as _GPIO
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!
```

My program is as follows:

```py
from RPIO import PWM

servo = PWM.Servo()

# Set servo on GPIO17 to 1200µs (1.2ms)
servo.set_servo(17, 1200)

# Set servo on GPIO17 to 2000µs (2.0ms)
servo.set_servo(17, 2000)

# Clear servo on GPIO17
servo.stop_servo(17)
```

This is on Python 3.4.2 on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B v1.2.

This is result on Python 2.7.9:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Python_Ed/RPIO_server_test2.7.py", line 1, in <module>
    from RPIO import PWM
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/RPIO/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/RPIO/_GPIO.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/RPIO/_GPIO.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I also tried from command line. and I get ioctl_set_msg failed: -1. BTW, I am kinda a newbie.

Comment: **"Try running as root!"**

Comment: I suspect you are not following the instructions.  As @Milliways points out the error message also tells you what to try.